# ImportError: No module named 'urwid'

Tags: python, pypy, urwid

I'm have an issue within a python 2.7 (pypy) script which has the code below

```
from urwid import ExitMainLoop
```

It's showing me the error in the title of this question even though it's been installed via pip and can be seen in the output when running **pip freeze**

```
urwid==1.3.1
```

This is running on a Raspberry PI 3 in Raspbian and the same set of scripts are running without issue on a Debian VM.

Any help very much appreciated?

Comment: if you try just `pypy -c 'import urwid'`, what error do you get?

Comment: Thanks for replying, however I figured it out in the end, it was a bit of a n00b to python error as the urwid lib wasn't installed within the pypy scope, only the python scope